# JFileChooser, is it possible to return current directory without clicking anything else than add?

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I would like to have the following (if possible):

- the user wants to add some files, he opens the File Chooser
- without clicking/selecting any files or directory, he clicks instead directly on the add button
- all the files contained in the current directory will be retrieved

Is it feasible?

Comment: Sure its quite possible. You are gonna have to make your own custom button that simply has that action listener. But yeah very very possible

Comment: Nice to hear that... could you write a couple of lines as hint or suggest any link in regards?

Comment: When the file chooser returns the directory path, then you can use the list functions in the `File` object to iterate the files. If there are sub-directories you will have to recursively search.

Comment: *When the file chooser returns the directory path* is the hard part ;)